# Binary Search Tree with categorical and numeric values in python

Tags: python

I coded bst in python and it is working for both categorical and numeric values. Is it draws tree with ASCI value.? So in Isolation Forest algorithm how it is helping to get better accuracy than considering only numeric features and removing categorical features?

Thank you.

Comment: Random forest is a set of classification trees. Classification trees are not related to binary search trees.

Answer (score 0):

[image]

If PlayTennis is your target classification label, you could map the numeric values to intervalls. Finding appropriate intervalls can be done by first sorting the numeric values and then using Intervalls at which there is a change in your target label. In this case we have a change between 48 and 60, and between 80 and 90. (48+60)/2 = 54 and (80+90)/2 = 85 are good candidates for label-intervalls. (T>54) and (T>85) would be the labels.